# AttributeError object has no attribute to "find_all"

Tags: python, html

Hello I am making a corona tracker 
and getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sir.py", line 60, in <module>
    mainLabel = tk.Label(root, text=get_corona_detail_of_india(), font=f, bg='white')
  File "sir.py", line 22, in get_corona_detail_of_india
    info_div = bs.find("div", class_="information_row").find_all("div", class_="iblock")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Code:

```
def get_corona_detail_of_india():
    url = "https://www.mohfw.gov.in/"
    html_data = get_html_data(url)
    bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_data.text, 'html.parser')
    info_div = bs.find("div", class_="information_row").find_all("div", class_="iblock")
    all_details = ""
    for block in info_div:
        count = block.find("span", class_="icount").get_text()
        text = block.find("div", class_="info_label").get_text()
        all_details = all_details + text + " : " + count + "\n"
    return all_details
```

Comment: `bs.find("div", class_="information_row")` didn't find anything to return.

Comment: Please include the traceback message. Python gave you valuable debug information... pass it on.

Comment: hey, thanks but can u explain to me what should I do, actually I am a beginner.

Comment: Put the result of `find()` in a variable. Check whether it's set before trying to call `find_all`.

Answer (score 1):

Put the result of `find()` in a variable so you can check that it found something before trying to use `find_all()`.

```
def get_corona_detail_of_india():
    url = "https://www.mohfw.gov.in/"
    html_data = get_html_data(url)
    bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_data.text, 'html.parser')
    info_row = bs.find("div", class_="information_row")
    if info_row:
        info_div = info_row.find_all("div", class_="iblock")
        all_details = ""
        for block in info_div:
            count = block.find("span", class_="icount").get_text()
            text = block.find("div", class_="info_label").get_text()
            all_details = all_details + text + " : " + count + "\n"
        return all_details
    else:
        return ""
```

Alternatively you can use a selector instead of `find()`.

```
info_div = bs.select("div.information_row div.iblock")
```